# Distribute Cell Value Over Column of Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I want to distribute a value over a column of cells in multiples of 0.25.  For instance, if my value is 6 and my column consists of 10 cells, I want 6 of the cells to have a value of 0.5 and 4 of the cells to have a value of 0.75 to sum to 6.

Another example would be if the value was 1 and I wanted to distribute that over the same column of 10 cells.  4 of the cells should have a value of 0.25 and 6 should have a value of 0.

The unequal cells could either be the first 4 in the column or randomly selected from the 10.

Comment: What is the pattern? Your first and second examples are very different. How would any process "know" to make the last four cells zero in the 2nd example, when compared to the 1st example?

Comment: We need more information. Like is your result always in the same column and is the # of columns having the data always the same? Could you give us a screenshot of the spreadsheet as an example?

Comment: lol you hero, you can deadpan this morning but not afternoon? Man, you troll me so hard XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires the following:

1. Range to enter variables located at `B3:C6` *(see fig. 1)*

   **Number**: Number to be distributed. Enter `6` in `C3`

   **Divider**: Enter `0.25` in `C4`

   **Parts**: Number of parts to distribute. Enter `10` in `C5`

   **Multiples**: Formula to calculate & validate the parts to be allocated. Enter this formula in `C6`

   ```
   =IF( MOD( $C$3 , $C$4 ) <> 0 , "!Err" , $C$3 / $C$4 )
   ```
2. Range to calculate the distribution located at `E2:G13` *(see fig. 1)*

   **Parts**: Keeps the relationship between distribution and part number. Enter this formula in `E3` then copy till last record

   ```
   =SUM( 1 , E2 )
   ```

   **Times**: Number of times each part number contains the multiple. Enter this formula in `F3` then copy till last record

   ```
   =SUM( INT( $C$6 / $C$5 ) , IF( $E3 <= MOD( $C$6 , $C$5 ) , 1 , 0 ) )
   ```

   **Distribution**: Resulting distribution. Enter this formula in `G3` then copy till last record

   ```
   = $C$4 * $F3
   ```

   **Total**: validation of the distribution. Enter this formula in `E3` then copy till last record

   ```
   =IF( ROUND( SUM( $G$3:$G$12 , -$C$3 ) , 2 ) <> 0 , "!Err" , $C$3 )
   ```

   [image]
   Fig. 1

   [image]
   Fig. 2

Comment: Perfect!  This is the exact answer I was looking for.  Thanks so much for the clear explanation and figures.